# I cannot get jQuery or jQuery UI to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, click, fadeout

I can't seem to get jQuery or jQuery UI to work
This is my code:

Referenced files:

```
<script scr="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Code I am trying to execute:

```
//Welcome message fading away
        ( document ).ready(function(){
            $( "#welcome" ).click(function() {
               $( "p" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
                    //animation is complete
               });
            });
        });
```

HTML Code

```
<div class="JSContent">
                <p id="welcome">Hello, this is a test<br> Click me to make me go away.</p>
            </div>
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: I load jQuery using: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> Also, ( document ).ready(function(){ should be      $( document ).ready(function(){

Comment: Also, just a tip...use "this" where you can...example here:        $( document ).ready(function(){
            $( "#welcome" ).click(function() {
               $(this).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
                    //animation is complete
               });
            });
        });

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your jQuery code is wrong. You lack `$` on the start of your code. (Or just typo error)

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrw5pj33/)

Comment: How did this get 3 upvotes? Not trying to be a jerk, but some of my answers have like 10-20 lines of code and literally 1 semicolon missing (and is otherwise correct) and I get at least 2 downvotes....this was just invoking jQuery with the jQuery alias....Google would answer this just as well

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
$( "#welcome" ).click(function() {
    $( "p" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
        //animation is complete
    });
});
```

Keep in mind that this script has to be **below** your code like this:

```
<div id="welcome">Click Me</div>
<p>Fade me out</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#welcome" ).click(function() {
    $( "p" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
        //animation is complete
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m2rhnetm/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script scr="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script>

//Welcome message fading away

 $( document ).ready(function(){
        $( "#welcome" ).click(function() {
           $( "p" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
                //animation is complete
           });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery API is universally accessed through the $ function. For your example, you need to replace where you call the document ready function with an actual call to the jQuery API. At the moment, you aren't calling anything on the document object, and by extension, you are instead trying to access a document.ready function which doesn't exist.

i.e replace:

```
( document ).ready(function(){
...
```

with:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
...
```

For more information, jump into the [jQuery Docs](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/)